# Weird BeginInvoke Behaviour C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In one of my C# 4.0 windows app I am facing unusual behaviour with (most probably) BeginInvoke. I have a login form on which an ID is generated each time user tries to login, the ID authorization is written to a file, which login form is watching using FileSystemWatcher. On authorization an event is generated which is captured by main form.

Now my issue is that old IDs show up at the time of verification, even though each time a new instance of LoginForm in created at the time of login process. First time the ID value in strID variable is correct but from then on for each consecutive login, previous IDs show up.

It is difficult for me to explain it in words correctly, so I am attaching the code for login form. The weird behaviour I am facing is at `if(arrData[0] == this.strID)` part of `GetAuthorizationStatus` function. Please help me understand whether this is an expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong here.

Login form have 3 buttons : btnLogin for getting the ID, btnExit to exit the form and btnAuth for authenticating (I have put it here for testing, instead of another app/service)

Following is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleInvokeTest
{
    public class AuthEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private string strID;
        private DateTime dtLoginAt;
        private bool isAuthorized;

        public AuthEventArgs(string ID, DateTime LoginAt, bool isAuthorized)
        {
            this.strID = ID;
            this.dtLoginAt = LoginAt;
            this.isAuthorized = isAuthorized;
        }

        public string ID
        { get{ return this.strID; } }

        public DateTime LoginAt
        { get{ return this.dtLoginAt; } }

        public bool IsAuthorized
        { get{ return this.isAuthorized; } }
    }

    public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        delegate void ShowDelegate();

        private string strID = "";
        private const string FILE_PATH = @"E:\test.txt";
        private DateTime dtLastResultReadTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        private DateTime dtLoginAt = DateTime.MinValue;
        private bool isAuthorized = false;
        private string strLoginErrorMessage ="";

        public event EventHandler<AuthEventArgs> AuthOccurred; 

        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FileSystemWatcher fswAuth = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetDirectoryName(FILE_PATH));
            fswAuth.Filter = Path.GetFileName(FILE_PATH);
            fswAuth.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            fswAuth.Changed+= new FileSystemEventHandler(fswAuth_Changed);
            fswAuth.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            tmrTimeout.Interval = 5000;
            tmrTimeout.Tick+= new EventHandler(tmrTimeout_Tick);
        }

        void fswAuth_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dtTempReadAt = File.GetLastWriteTime(FILE_PATH);
            if (dtLastResultReadTime < dtTempReadAt)
            {
                dtLastResultReadTime = dtTempReadAt;
                GetAuthorizationStatus();
            }
        }

        private void GetAuthorizationStatus()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(new ShowDelegate(GetAuthorizationStatus));
            }
            else
            {
                string strData = ",";
                tmrTimeout.Enabled = false;

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FILE_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        try
                        { strData = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); }
                        catch (Exception)
                        { //log error }
                    }
                }

                string[] arrData = strData.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                if (arrData.Length == 2)
                {

                    if(arrData[0] == this.strID)
                    {
                        if (arrData[1] == "Y")
                        {
                            tmrTimeout.Enabled = false;
                            this.lblWait.Visible = false;
                            this.btnExit.Enabled = true;
                            this.btnLogin.Enabled = false;
                            this.isAuthorized = true;
                            this.strLoginErrorMessage = "";

                            onAuthOccurred(new AuthEventArgs(this.strID, this.dtLoginAt, this.isAuthorized));
                            this.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Authorization failed
                            tmrTimeout.Enabled = false;
                            this.lblWait.Visible = false;
                            this.btnExit.Enabled = true;
                            this.btnLogin.Enabled = true;

                            //also clear local variables
                            this.strID = "";
                            this.dtLoginAt = DateTime.MinValue;
                            this.isAuthorized = false;
                            this.strLoginErrorMessage = "Authorization denied.";
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!this.isAuthorized && this.strLoginErrorMessage != "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this.strLoginErrorMessage, "Authorization denied", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }

        void tmrTimeout_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmrTimeout.Enabled = false;
            this.lblWait.Visible = false;
            this.btnExit.Enabled = true;
            this.btnLogin.Enabled = true;

            //also clear local variables
            this.strID="";
            this.isAuthorized = false;
            this.dtLoginAt = DateTime.MinValue;

            MessageBox.Show("Timeout occurred while waiting for authorization.", "Authorization timeout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void onAuthOccurred(AuthEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<AuthEventArgs> handler = AuthOccurred;

            if (handler != null)
            { handler(this, e); }
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.dtLoginAt = DateTime.Now;
            this.strID = IDGenerator.GetNewID().ToString();

            this.btnLogin.Enabled = false;
            this.btnExit.Enabled = false;
            tmrTimeout.Enabled = true;
            lblWait.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to cancel login?", "Cancel Login", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Clear local variables
                this.strID="";
                this.isAuthorized = false;
                this.dtLoginAt = DateTime.MinValue;
                //raise event and exit
                onAuthOccurred(new AuthEventArgs(this.strID, this.dtLoginAt, this.isAuthorized));
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        void BtnAuthClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(FILE_PATH,string.Format("{0},Y",this.strID));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: Just wondering why use a file to transfer information? Does anything change if you just for a test add a delay of one second in the watcher's event before reading the file? Might be the events are about writing, but the file hasn't actually been written yet. Though then I would assume reading the file wouldn't succeed either.

Comment: Actually the project is divided in several parts. The code I have given here is for a sample project which I created after facing similar issue in my project. One app is for users where he/she will login and the login is verified by another app running on network. I didn't keep the n/w code in the same app as I will be running it as a service and wit will also be keeping track for communication with various other apps/hardware.

Comment: @leppie I have tried with Invoke also, but the behaviour is same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     FileSystemWatcher fswAuth = new FileSystemWatcher(...);
```

This is where the problem started.  You **must** dispose the watcher when your form closes, the FormClosed event is good for that.  Or just dropping one from the toolbox, now it is completely automatic.  But you don't, it just keeps watching after the window is closed.  And keeps raising events.

That *usually* triggers an ObjectDisposedException, but it doesn't have to.  You'll also leak the form object, it cannot be garbage collected.  Misery multiplies when you create another instance of this form, now you have *two* FSWs monitoring for file changes.  The old one still uses the old ID, that's what you see back in the file.

Keep in mind that this is not where the problems end, the user could start your program again, now you inevitably have two FSWs that disagree about the proper ID.

You need to re-think this.  A server-style app is the usual solution.  A short-term workaround is keeping the FSW separate in a static class so there is only ever one instance of it.  And ensuring that your program can run only once, a "single-instance app".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. As of now I have done a quick duct tape patch for the problem. I have made FSW as a private variable and added it to the components collection, so that it gets disposed when the form gets disposed. Please let me know whether it is the right solution or should I change it to explicitly dispose FSW at form close? TIA

Comment: I don't know if it is the correct solution, no idea why you want to use FSW at all.  Why would the file change if it can only work properly when a single instance of your program changes it?  Gut-feeling is that you should eliminate it completely.

Comment: Actually the program is divided in several parts. When the user logs in, the ID is sent to another machine where another user authorizes the login. I have kept a separate service which takes input from the file and sends data over n/w to other app and the results are sent back to the service which writes the result in file. This file is read by FSW to get the result in UI. The interface is 2 ways, one file to write from UI and read by service and other file write by service and read by UI.

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way around, only that service can reliably create new IDs.  Talk to it with a named pipe, socket or WCF.

Comment: The code I posted here is not the actual code. This code I created to test the behaviour I was facing in actual app. In actual app the ID is generated by database identity. The login is checked by DB and if login succeeded, a new login record is inserted in DB and record ID is retrieved, which is further used for authentication along with the user details.

Comment: Actually I created the sample app as the actual code is huge. There are a lot of external interfaces (s/w and h/w) with the app and any one can fail at any time. I have tried to keep the UI as much independent from other interfaces as much as possible, so that failure in any one component does not interfere with the UI. I have used file based interface as it is the easiest and quite fast.  I have used 2 files where 2 way interface is required, so that no deadlock or race condition is created. Only one modules writes and only one module reads.